# How to parallelize d3.js or cubism.js

Tags: javascript, parallel-processing, coffeescript, d3.js, cubism.js

I'm following the examples on http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/

Example:

```
var p = new Parallel([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 
        log = function () { console.log(arguments); };

function fib(n) {
  return n < 2 ? 1 : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
};

p.map(fib).then(log)
```

Works beautifully, now I want to apply the same concept on d3 objects.

I have a for loop that loops through a list of names:

```
for name in names by 1
  // set some stuff
  context = [....]
  metrics = [....]

  d3.select("#"+name)
    .selectAll(".horizon")
    .data(metrics).enter()
    .insert("div", ".bottom")
    .attr("class", "horizon")
    .call context.horizon()
```

If I put the the content of the for loop in the function fib content it complains about "undefined d3 variable" ... but I feel like I'm missing the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parallelize the chain. There's nothing special about d3 here - when you chain calls, i.e. `foo(a).bar(b).foobar(c)` it means that `foo()` returns an object with method `bar()` which in turn returns object with method `foobar()`. This essentially means that you can't run `foo()` and `bar()` in parallel, because the latter requires result from the former.

Comment: Yes, but what If I'm generating this whole chained event 40 times, I can't still do it I guess because It's manipulating the DOM as I read yesterday.

Comment: Parallel.js uses web workers, which can not, as of now, access DOM

Answer (score 0):

I can't parallelize d3.select

but I was able to parallelize only the part that builds the array metrics but that almost did nothing --- 1 second less?

I'm going to post my solution if I find anything